# shall not be more than vs. shall be not more than?

Tags: grammar

> It shall be not more than 1m.
>
> It shall not be more than 1m.

Which is the correct way to say "it shall be less than or equal to 1m"?
Two expressions are mixed in Google, so I want to know what native speakers say exactly.

thank you.

Comment: In this context, both are correct. They have the same meaning.

Comment: As a native speaker, I feel more comfortable saying "It shall not be . . .." As for "It shall be less than or equal to . . .," the sentence sounds fine to me.  Why "It shall not be" as opposed to "It shall be not"? To reduce the chances of being misunderstood by the person to whom the instruction is being given. Ask yourself, "Which expression will stick in the mind of the hearer better, especially if there's a delay between the hearing and the doing?: It shall be not, or It shall not be (particularly if the word "not" is emphasized in the latter)? Something to think about. Don